# Multiple webhooks in Parse.com

Tags: parse-platform, webhooks, ngrok

As of [Parse's announcement](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/introducing-cloud-code-webhooks/) of Cloud Code Webhooks, I've build my own server environment instead of using Parse Cloud Code.

I'm running my server locally, changing the Parse webhook to point at my ngrok tunnel, [as described here](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-cli).

This all works great, but one problem arises when more people from my team, has to work on the server, on the same time. Since the webhook to Parse only can (AFAIK) point to one single webhook URL, we can only have one server running, pointing to its localhost address, through ngrok.

Is anyway to create a workaround for this problem?

Feel free to ask my elaborate on any of my points.